# Convert Database From MSAccess to SQlite for android

Tags: android, sqlite, ms-access

I have a database of MSAccess and now i want to convert into SQLite database. Is it possible? If yes and if you have any idea related to it than please Share with me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done this way:

1. Export Database from MSAccess as a Text File
2. Save this text file to your local hard disk
3. Open SQLite data browser
4. Create new Database
5. Import saved text file as **Import Table From CSV File**
6. Create table for database
7. Save database

**Done**

Comment: this method is not good if your database contains forty tables with eighty relationships, constrains...

Comment: This is not a solution, please look at https://www.sqlite.org/cvstrac/wiki?p=ConverterTools

Answer (score 5):

you can convert it using following tools:

https://www.sqlite.org/cvstrac/wiki?p=ConverterTools

http://mdb2sq3.codeplex.com/

http://www.basic4ppc.com/forum/code-samples-tips/78-how-convert-access-database-sqlite-database.html

Comment: Just to let you know, the first link now appears to be dead

Comment: The second link also appears to now be dead.

Answer (score 4):

if your database contains forty tables with eighty relationships, constrains
you can try to use:
https://github.com/arturasn/mdb2sqlite

Executable direct download:
https://github.com/arturasn/mdb2sqlite/blob/master/bin/mdb2sqlite.exe