# Is it possible to write an Android App that uses a Microsoft Access database?

Tags: android, ms-access, ucanaccess

I am writing an Android app that I would like to have communicate with an Access database. I am trying to use [UCanAccess](http://ucanaccess.sourceforge.net/site.html) to communicate with database through the app whenever it is launched, but it keeps crashing without any output to tell me what the problem is. Since UCanAccess is not working, is there perhaps some other way I can establish communication with the database for reading and writing?

Comment: Interesting and never tried. Could you describe your case - are you downloading access file on android or bundle it with app?

Comment: @EugenMartynov On the first run of the application, the database is extracted from the app resources and saved on the device.

Comment: If it is not critical, I would convert ms db to sqlite (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17170083/convert-database-from-msaccess-to-sqlite-for-android)

Comment: The only problem is that I do not know how to use sqlite. I have absolutely no experience with it.

Comment: I suspect it would be much easier to learn sqlite than it would be to get MS Access working on Android.

Comment: I second @EugenMartynov, the time spent trying to figure out how to get a MS-Access db into android could be better spent just doing it in SQLite. If you're looking to create the database in some sort of graphical editor I would advise you check out SQLiteAssetHelper (https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper), then use a tool like SQLite Database Browser to make the database.

Comment: @EugenMartynov Thank you to both of you! I have used a graphical editor to recreate my database in SQLite, and I am currently in the process of implementing communication with the database in my app. One more question though: could I modify the database from directly within my app's resources or do I need to extract it to a file? I am currently extracting it to a file which I then use, but I do not know if that is necessary.

Comment: @DavidB, you need to extract it from assets (same as you did with ms db) and after point your SQL helper to it

Comment: @EugenMartynov Okay, thanks! Just wanted to make sure there was not a more efficient way to go about it.